# How can I solve the problem when reading a registry entry?

Tags: c++, winapi, registry

i want to get the value from an registry entry. Here is my code:

```
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <atlstr.h>
#include <iostream>
#define BUFFER 8192
int main()
{
    char value[255];
    DWORD BufferSize = BUFFER;
    RegGetValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\ComputerName\\ActiveComputerName", L"ComputerName", RRF_RT_REG_SZ, NULL, (PVOID)&value, &BufferSize);
    std::cout << value << std::endl;
}
```

My Computer name is: **DESKTOP-IGW3F**.
But if i run my program my output is: **D**

I have no idea how to fix it...i hope you can help me.

Comment: Is it encoded using UTF-16le?

Comment: Yes it encoded using UTF-16le. Thats whyi am using RRF_RT_REG_SZ.

Comment: DE... is a 44 00 45 00 ... and you're treating it as a NUL-terminated string

Comment: The code says the buffer size is 8192, but the buffer provided only has 255.  255 is much less than 8192.  That could result in problems.  (Probably not a problem in this case, but in general.)  A UTF-16LE *encoding unit* does not fit in a `char`; you'll need to convert the result from UTF-16LE to ASCII (assuming the data fits in 7-bit ASCII) string.

Comment: i changed it, but it isnt workig

Comment: `char` is not correct for a wide character string.

Comment: `char` -> `wchar_t`

Comment: Is there a reason why you are reading the computer name from the Registry instead of using the `GetComputerName()` API?

Answer (score 1):

The Win32 function `RegGetValue()` does not exist. It is only a preprocessor macro that will resolve to either `RegGetValueA()` or `RegGetValueW()` depending on your project settings. In your case, the macro resolves to `RegGetValueW()`, therefore it treats the registry value as a Unicode string (2 bytes per character). But you are using a `char` (1 byte per character) buffer to receive the Unicode data.

To make your code work, you need to either explicitly call `RegGetValueA()` instead, or change your buffer type from `char` to `wchar_t`. Either way, you should also check the return value of the function.

A working example could look like this:

```c
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    WCHAR value[255];
    DWORD bufferSize = 255 * sizeof(WCHAR);

    if (!RegGetValueW(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\ComputerName\\ActiveComputerName", L"ComputerName", RRF_RT_REG_SZ, NULL, value, &bufferSize))
    {
        std::wcout << value << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: But if i try to get the value from Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\RegisteredOwner, its not working.

Comment: @user187 then you will need to show the code that is not working for that.

Comment: @user187 `RegisteredOwner` is the name of the value, not a sub key of `CurrentVersion` as your reply indicates. Other than that, it should work in the same way.